# Comma inside enum value definition?

Tags: c, enums, clang

I have the following flag enum definition (Cocoa macros used):

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(uint64_t, ItemDataType) {

...

    A = (1 << 16),
    B = (1 << 17),
    C = (1 << 18),
...

    G = (1 << 31),

    TEST = (A | B | C, G)
};
```

`TEST` was supposed to be  `(A | B | C | G)` but we made a typo and entered `(A | B | C, G)`. What is the meaning of this notation? What is the actual value of `TEST`? Isn't this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`,` is the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), it is valid code, it will evaluate the left operand and then throw away the value and evaluate the right operand and that will be the result.

From the C99 draft standard section `6.5.17` *Comma operator* paragraph *2*:

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point after its evaluation. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its
>   type and value.<sup>97)</sup>

Also worth noting that the comma operator has the [lowest operator precedence](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html).

`clang` with provide the following warning if you use the `-Weverything` flag:

```
warning: expression is not an integer constant expression; folding it to a constant is a GNU extension [-Wgnu-folding-constant]
TEST = (A | B | C , G)
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

which is correct the value has to be a constant expression which it is not since constant expressions can not contain the comma operator.

`gcc` in this case gives me an error but also a warning if I use the `-Wall` flag:

```
warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 TEST = (A | B | C , G)
                   ^
error: enumerator value for 'TEST' is not an integer constant
```

Comment: The key is the parentheses. If there were no parentheses, then it would store the value of `A | B | C`, but as it stands right now, it stores the value of `G`. The comma operator has the lowest precedence of any C operator, and acts as a sequence point.

Comment: Can you provide a real-world example where this operator would be used in a context such as this? The compiler should at least throw a warning.

Comment: @LeoNatan: Why should it throw a warning? Would (a += 2, b += 3); throw a warning? What if that's the desired effect?

Comment: @GIJoe Why does `if(a=3) { }` throw a warning? There are certain things which are obscure and should not be allowed. What is the value of comma operator inside the enum value definition?

Comment: @LeoNatan: Your example is plain wrong syntax, my example is valid. You could just as easily manipulate a value like I showed in the left side and store a different value in the right (and -Wall shows the warning).